# bash grep finding java declarations

Tags: regex, bash, grep

i have a huge .java file and i want to find all declared objects given the className. i think the declaration will always have the following signature:

className objName;

or

className objName =

or

className objName=

can someone suggest me a grep pattern which will find these signatures. I have the following (incomplete)  :

```
    cat $rootFile | grep "$className "
```

EXAMPLE :

If the input file is :

```
Policy pol1;
Policy pol2 ;
Policy   pol3  ;
Policy pol4=new Policy();
Policy pol5 = new Policy();
Policy pol6= new Policy();
```

I want to extract the following list :

```
pol1
pol2
pol3
pol4
pol5
pol6
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use `cat`. Both `grep` and Perl (used in an answer below) accept filenames as arguments. Also, `grep` is not part of Bash so there's no such thing as "bash grep".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably perl can help here

```
cat $rootFilename | perl -pe 's/Policy[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[ \t]*[;=].*/\1/g'
```

Using sed, can be done as well

```
sed -e 's/Policy[ \t]\+\([a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\)[ \t]*[;=].*/\1/g' $rootFilename
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. Otherwise +1.

Comment: Great thanks. This one work. Thanks to everyone for the contribution.